# Unity: Shooter 2D-Character animation only runs once

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I wanted my animation to play whenever my character shoots the gun but currently the animation runs only when it fires the first time and not the others. I have the impression that it will be something very simple in the code but I have been around here and still have not found a solution. Can someone give me a hint, please?

Here is the animation part in the code:

```
private Animator myAnimator;
private bool isFire;
private string FireAnimHash = "isFire";

void Awake()
{
    spriteRend = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
}

void Start()
{
    myAnimator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    myAnimator.enabled =true;
    myAnimator.SetBool (FireAnimHash ,isFire);
}

private void Update()
{
    AimArmAtMouse();

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        isFire = true;
        myAnimator.SetBool (FireAnimHash ,isFire);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to have two opening braces under your `Update` method?

Comment: Eliasar, that s not all the code of this script ...only the Animation 
parte...i have other functions in the same script...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you use Triggers, not bools, when animating these types of animations, which become true and then false.
Copy the below script and change the variable type to trigger from bool in animator tab in unity.
It should work.

```
 private Animator myAnimator;
 private string FireAnimHash = "isFire";

 void Awake()
 {
     spriteRend = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
 }

 void Start()
 {
    myAnimator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    myAnimator.enabled = true;
 }

 private void Update()
 {
     AimArmAtMouse();

     if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
     {
       myAnimator.SetTrigger(FireAnimHash);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, this game its my hobby...im working late last night...i only tried this code now....but now its not shooting at all...i have to get more closer to the code to see my mistake...

Comment: you have to change the variable to trigger from bool

Comment: Go to animator tab and add a trigger variable in properties tab of animator and rename that variable to isFire. Delete the already created bool isFire and then run the script it should work. Suppose u want to go to Fire state from ideal state when FireAnimHash Trigger is pulled then make transistion from ideal to Fire and set the condition to isFire and make anathor transition from Fire to ideal state with no condition in it and dont edit HasExitTime. HasExitTime has to be checked. Try this it will work.

Comment: .i did like you said and change the variable but now he plays the animation only once and before i click the mouse...and nothing more....when i click the mouse there is no animation now...

Comment: Naresh Bisht, it worked!! I needed to make one more transition in the animator. Thank you very much!! :) I have to resolve is the delay between the bullet shooted and the movement of the hand in the animation....

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your `isFire` is set to false after playing the shooting animation. If it has been true, and you have not transitioned it to other animations in the mecanim and did not set the animation to loop.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to set `isFire = false` somewhere in your code, or you need to use [`Animator.SetTrigger`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.SetTrigger.html).

---

## From Unity's Documentation

```
//Attach this script to a GameObject with an Animator component attached.
//For this example, create parameters in the Animator and name them “Crouch” and
// “Jump”

//Apply these parameters to your transitions between states

//This script allows you to trigger an Animator parameter and reset the other that
// could possibly still be active. Press the up and down arrow keys to do this.

using UnityEngine;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    Animator m_Animator;

    void Start()
    {
        //Get the Animator attached to the GameObject you are intending to animate.
        m_Animator = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //Press the up arrow button to reset the trigger and set another one
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            //Reset the "Crouch" trigger
            m_Animator.ResetTrigger("Crouch");

            //Send the message to the Animator to activate the trigger parameter named "Jump"
            m_Animator.SetTrigger("Jump");
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            //Reset the "Jump" trigger
            m_Animator.ResetTrigger("Jump");

            //Send the message to the Animator to activate the trigger parameter named "Crouch"
            m_Animator.SetTrigger("Crouch");
        }
    }
}
```